# include in log elevated sudo users

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, ssh, auditd

I'm new here, but I tried looking but couldn't get how to do it...

I have an `ec2` linux box.
When a user directly connects to the machine I can view its ssh ip.
Now when a user does `sudo -s` for example it gets elevated to root, but the **source ip from which he did this sudo is lost** since it **does not seem to be ssh anymore**.

So my question is - How do I add the real elevated user's source ip to the log ?

**This is the script I use :**

```
#!/bin/bash -
# command line audit logging
function log2syslog
{
   declare COMMAND
   COMMAND=$(fc -ln -0)
   logger -p local1.notice -t bash -i -- "${USER}:${SUDO_USER}:${SSH_CLIENT}:${COMMAND}"
}
trap log2syslog DEBUG
```

This is an example of the log output it generates when user elevated

```
<141>Jan 31 13:13:30 ip-10-10-0-0 bash[5568]: root:ec2-user::::#011 cat /etc/xyz
```

This is an example of the log output it generates when user not elevated (its the same for user that connects directly to the machine)

```
<141>Jan 31 13:29:54 ip-10-10-0-0 bash[5768]: ec2-user::/dev/pts/1:172.16.204.4 22005 22:172.26.4.4 22005 10.10.0.0 22:#011 cat /etc/xyz
```

Help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell `sudo` to preserve that environment variable...

```
Defaults env_keep += "SSH_CLIENT"
```

...but beware that the user can simply change it before running `sudo`. In fact, they can even change it to a value containing colons, which will mess up your log parser. (In fact, with IPv6 addresses, this value *will* have colons in it.)

Comment: That's awesome !! Thank you ! that worked well ! 
and thanks for the heads up !
@user1686